# Create a grid of blocks similar to a Breakout game

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a simple clone of the Breakout game.

How can I render all the blocks in the grid in certain (x, y) positions?

The app shows the blocks but all in the same position.

[image: Breakout Game]

```
class Block {
  Random random = Random();
  Rect rect;
  Paint paint;
  Size size;

  Block({this.size}) {
    rect = Rect.fromLTWH(
        16,
        16,
        50,
        25);
    paint = Paint()..color = Colors.white;
  }

  void render(Canvas canvas){
      canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
  }

  void update(double td){

  }
}

class TestGame extends Game {

  Size screenSize;

  TestGame(this.screenSize);

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
      Block(size: screenSize).render(canvas);
    }
  }

  @override
  void update(double t) {} 
}
```

Comment: Please break this down into a specific problem that someone can easily answer.

Comment: I removed some code but that's it, there no way to make it easier to understand. The problem is generate the grid of blocks, how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now all the blocks are rendered in the same position since you don't change the coordinates of the `Rect`.

Your `Block` class needs to take the coordinates of where you want to place the tile, like this:

```
static final int width = 50;
static final int height = 25; 

Block(**int x, int y**) {
  rect = Rect.fromLTWH(**x**, **y**, Block.width, Block.height);
  paint = Paint()..color = Colors.white;
}
```

And then when you generate them you need to give them different coordinates in the loop in the render function, like this:

```
  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; < 5; j++) {
        // This could be moved out to the constructor and put in a list so that
        // you wont have to make a new object in every render
        Block((i+1)*Block.width, (j+2)*Block.height);
      }
    }
  }
```

(The i+1 and j+2 for the coordinates are to make it look like in your image, if you remove the +1 and +2 you will start rendering in the upper left corner)

It will just look like a big block of white now, but if you either make some space between each tile, give them different colors or edges, you will see all the tiles.

Easiest way to see it would be with: `paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;`